# Is this a jquery content slider? if yes how can I get it

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-scrollable

Please visit the link below and check that content slider out cause I love it

[The Link](http://bit.ly/8ligiE)

Thank  you

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry! That is a flash stuff